# Unknown exception by boost::serialization in windows

Tags: c++, exception, boost-serialization

This is what I've tried, but I am getting `Error: Unknown exception` thrown

```
try{//load
  std::ifstream stream(arch_name.c_str());
  std::cout << ">> " << "Started deserializing " << arch_name << std::endl;
  boost::archive::binary_iarchive arc(stream);
  arc & c & matrix;
  stream.close();
  std::cout << ">> " << "Finished deserializing" << std::endl;
}catch(std::exception e){
  std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  return 1;
}
```

This is working well in Linux with gcc. I am using Visual Studio in windows.

### Edit

backtrace is showing that `basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp` is throwing exception on

```
template<class Archive, class Elem, class Tr>
inline void basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive, Elem, Tr>::load_binary( void *address,     std::size_t count){
//.....
if(scount != s)
    boost::serialization::throw_exception(
        archive_exception(archive_exception::input_stream_error)
    );
```

### Edit

I changed the `catch` black to `catch(boost::archive::archive_exception e)` and it printed. `input stream error`

Is there any miss in virtual what in boost archive exception ?

Comment: Can you tell which statement throws the exception?

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?  Enable first-chance exception handling (Debug -> Exceptions, check the C++ Exceptions box).

Comment: Was the binary archive written under Windows?

Comment: Yes Thats the option I was looking here and there. I am first time on VisualStudio

Comment: Its throwing on binary_iarchive 's contructor `boost::archive::binary_iarchive arc(stream);`

Comment: Yes It was written under windows. Is there any way to copy paste the backtrace ?

Comment: Is it possible, that archive was corrupted between writing and reading?

Comment: Nope archive is not corrupted

Comment: You miss `std::ios::binary`. It seems to be required on Windows (otherwise EOL characters are corrupted).

Comment: Now getting `Class name too long` Error

Comment: Do you use `std::ios::binary` flag also when creating archive?

Comment: Oh! Yes. I forgot. Thanks. fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

I ran across this question because I had the same problem - a boost serialisation exception on Windows.  I found the solution in Greg's comments: define the i/o mode when creating the data stream.

I changed this:

```
std::ofstream ofs(filename);
boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(ofs);
```

To this:

```
std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(ofs);
```

And then no more exceptions occurred when deserialising!

I thought this question needed an actual answer (not just a comment), so I'm adding it myself, but all credit goes to Greg.

Comment: This solved my issue after two days of trying. THANK YOU!